# Need help on query on same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some data, and I need to make a query using that table.

I have:

```
+----+-----------------+--------+--------+
| Id | Name            | Parent |  Mark  |
+----+-----------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Name 1          |     0  |     0  |
|  2 | Name 2          |     1  |    20  |
|  3 | Name 3          |     2  |    45  |
|  4 | Name 4          |     0  |    50  |
+----+-----------------+--------+--------+
```

and I need:

```
+----+-----------------+--------+--------+
| Id | Name            | Parent |  Mark  |
+----+-----------------+--------+--------+
|  2 | Name 2          | Name 1 |    20  |
|  3 | Name 3          | Name 2 |    45  |
+----+-----------------+--------+--------+
```

How can I run the query in MySQL?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following using a `INNER JOIN`. Using this solution also exclude all rows without a matching parent.

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name, t2.Name AS Parent, t1.Mark
FROM table_name t1 INNER JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.Parent = t2.Id
ORDER BY t1.Id ASC
```

In case you want to see all rows (also the rows without (matching) parents) you can use the following with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name, t2.Name AS Parent, t1.Mark
FROM table_name t1 LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.Parent = t2.Id
ORDER BY t1.Id ASC
```

You can also use a sub-select instead of a join:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM table_name t2 WHERE t2.Id = t1.Parent) AS Parent, Mark 
FROM table_name t1
WHERE t1.Parent > 0
ORDER BY t1.Id ASC
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=185755477b8492529c36593902d2d3ff)

Comment: You have to replace `table_name` with your table name. `t1` and `t2` are table alias to join the table itself and to distinguish the columns. Also have a look at the demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your result by running this query.

```
Select tablename.* 
from tablename t1
inner join tablename t2 on t2.Id = t1.Parent ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the inner join in the same table and check if the user have parent or not 
try something like

```
select * from marksTbl m inner join marksTbl p on   m.Id = p.Parent
```